# Espaço entre mascara jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou usando uma mascara jquery:

```
            /// Mascara Telfone
            function mascara(o,f){
                v_obj=o
                v_fun=f
                setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
            }
            function execmascara(){
                v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
            }
            function mtel(v){
                v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");             //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
                v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"($1) $2"); //Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos
                v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");    //Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos
                return v;
            }
            function id( el ){
                return document.getElementById( el );
            }
            window.onload = function(){
                id('telefone_input').onkeyup = function(){
                    mascara( this, mtel );
                }
            }
```

Funciona legal, mas, preciso adicionar um espaço após o proximo digito depois do parenteses, separando o nono digito do próximo bloco de 4 digitos. Isso deve ocorrer se ele tiver o nono digito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi:

```
            /// Mascara Telfone
            function mascara(o,f){
                v_obj=o
                v_fun=f
                setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
            }
            function execmascara(){
                v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
            }
            function mtel(v){
                v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");             //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
                v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"($1) $2"); //Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos

                    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{8})$/,"$1 $2");    //Coloca espaço
                v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");    //Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos
                return v;
            }
            function id( el ){
                return document.getElementById( el );
            }
            window.onload = function(){
                id('telefone_input').onkeyup = function(){
                    mascara( this, mtel );
                }
            }
```